# How to install Magento 2.4.0?

Tags: magento2.4

I would like to install Magento 2.4.0 on server without Elasticsearch require during installation.
Can anybody tell me the way to disable Elasticsearch require when I run setup:install ... ?
Thank you so much.

Comment: you will need to install without sample data Magento 2.4 and one core file change in 
vendor\magento\module-elasticsearch\Setup\Validator.php  file around line no 36 function validate()  in that add to first line return $errors = []; 
-- after install you will be revert back core file changes because it just for installation

Comment: Thanks so much for your solution. This is very helpful.

Answer (score 6):

I've faced same problem while installing Magento 2.4 on my local setup due to elastic search module dependencies.

There are two ways to fix this problem (listed below).

1. Configure Elastic search on your server before installing the Magento 2.4.
2. Disable all elastic search module with below command before running the setup:install.

   ```
   php bin/magento module:disable Magento_Elasticsearch Magento_Elasticsearch6 Magento_Elasticsearch7 Magento_InventoryElasticsearch
   ```

Usually we're not using elastic search on local. So I prefer the 2nd way.

**Update:** As per @JayaChandra comment, we need to disable `Magento_ElasticsearchCatalogPermissions` module as well for Magento Commerce edition with the below additional command.

```
php bin/magento module:disable Magento_ElasticsearchCatalogPermissions
```

**Edit:** We can use the below module as an alternative of Elastic search. If you don't have elastic search installed on your server then you can use this module in Magento 2.4.x.

> https://swissuplabs.com/magento-2-mysql-legacy-search.html

Follow the below documentation to install/use Magento 2.4 without Elasticsearch.

> https://docs.swissuplabs.com/m2/extensions/search-mysql-legacy/

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Thank you. This helps me so much.

Comment: Thanks. it helps

Comment: Incase of commerce edition, we also need to add one more module in the above command "Magento_ElasticsearchCatalogPermissions"

Comment: Thank you @Jayachandra, I've updated my answer for Magento commerce edition.

Answer (score 1):

This video will help you to install Magento 2.4 with Elasticsearch.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3RFw9j4ihag